# Update a Column with sequential number based on the order by of a column in Oracle Sql

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, update

> I have table with below create scripts

```
create table training(  
 action_id       NUMBER not null,
 training_id       NUMBER,
 course_name       VARCHAR2(100),
 display_order     NUMBER default 0
```

)

> Below is the data

```
ACTION_ID   TRAINING_ID DISPLAY_ORDER
 675150      770650       0
 675150      780700       0
 675150      780701       0
 675180      770550       0
 675180      780800       0
 675180      780801       0
```

> I need write a db script that will update  DISPLAY_ORDER so that it
>   gets order from 1 order by  TRAINING_ID   for  a particular   ACTION_ID
>
> So outcome will be

```
ACTION_ID   TRAINING_ID DISPLAY_ORDER
 675150      770650       1
 675150      780700       2
 675150      780701       3
 675180      770550       1
 675180      780800       2
 675180      780801       3
```

Comment: Could you please provide the data as DML (`INSERT INTO training VALUES (...)`)? Help us to help you!

Answer (score 3):

```
create table training(  
 action_id       NUMBER not null,
 training_id       NUMBER,
 course_name       VARCHAR2(100),
 display_order     NUMBER default 0 
);

insert into training (action_id, training_id) values (675150, 770650);
insert into training (action_id, training_id) values (675150, 780700);
insert into training (action_id, training_id) values (675150, 780701);
insert into training (action_id, training_id) values (675180, 770550);
insert into training (action_id, training_id) values (675180, 780800);
insert into training (action_id, training_id) values (675180, 780801);
commit;

select action_id, training_id, display_order from training;

 ACTION_ID TRAINING_ID DISPLAY_ORDER
---------- ----------- -------------
    675150      770650             0
    675150      780700             0
    675150      780701             0
    675180      770550             0
    675180      780800             0
    675180      780801             0
```

Then with some magic:

```
merge into training t using
(select action_id, training_id, row_number() over (partition by action_id order by training_id)
  as display_order
from training) t2
on (t.action_id = t2.action_id and t.training_id = t2.training_id)
when matched then update set t.display_order = t2.display_order;
commit;

select action_id, training_id, display_order from training;

 ACTION_ID TRAINING_ID DISPLAY_ORDER
---------- ----------- -------------
    675150      770650             1
    675150      780700             2
    675150      780701             3
    675180      770550             1
    675180      780800             2
    675180      780801             3
```

Comment: Nice (+1)! I was going to post the same thing which I got from my pal [Mr. Google](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48141854/470530)! Spent ages (well, 1hr 45mins) messing around with different constructs without success :-( ! However, I have a question - **surely** there's a way of doing a simple `UPDATE` for what is (or should be) a relatively simple query?

Comment: @Balazs Papp    Great ! +1 for answer. Please upvote if you find the question insightful.